# Python import requests hangsup Android application

Tags: python, android, kivymd

I have working well Python script on windows and ubuntu with

```
import kivy
import requests
```

in it, its compiles to apk successfuly, and i am not using requests in it, but if i run this apk on android 11 it hangsup application, if i put

```
#import requests
```

it works well on android, buildoser specs have requests in it in both cases.
Is there any restrictions to use requests in Android app?

no additional questions

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i can't found answer in internet.... And decided to make some debug

```
adb longcat python:I *:S
```

is very helpfull command for it, so i found that my application asks for
urllib3 , chardet , charset_normalizer , idna modules
I have to add them to requirements string in buildozer.spec
and app starts succesfully